# NHibernate delete rows from all tables with given prefix where update_date is older than some date

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, nhibernate

I am trying to use `NHibernate` to go through all tables with the given prefix and in those tables delete all rows where column "`updated_date`" is older than some given date.

It's a part of a maintenance job trying to delete old data from the database.

I tried two approaches.

First I tried to create NamedQuery, but when I used table name as a parameter I got this error:

> could not execute native bulk manipulation query SQL: `here is the whole query` SQL not available

Second I tried using simple string query, but this time the call failed with this error:

> prefix_mytable is not mapped [delete from prefix_mytable where updated_date <= to_date('1.1.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')]

So taking the above into account. Is something like this even possible in NHibernate?

I know I could create a mapping for all the tables one by one. But the list is quite large and can change. It would seem really dumb if I had to update it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Linq queries.

`session.Query<Entity>().Where(e => e.UpdatedDate >= givenDate).Delete()`

`Delete()` extension method is used from NHibernate.Linq namespace. You can check it in the [NHibernate documentation](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html) chapter **18.6.3. Deleting entities**

Comment: Problem is that there is no general type used. Each table has a different structure. Moreover in your answer I don't see any way to specify the prefix of the tables as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: NHibernate is a strong typed ORM, for maintenance task i think you should not use it. You can build your own sql query based on Entity reflexion (to match given prefix), and run it through NHibernate (it will run sql on current session connexion).